# Test case for testing a textbox in c# with NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit

I want to test a textbox to determine if is empty or not (at a press of button for example), within a graphic Interface in C# with NUnit.

I do not really know how to write this kind of test case in the test method in my test class and searching the internet did not quite help me (or I did not know where to look).

I only found tescases like sum of 2 numbers and the expected result, but none with the interface.

So, I thought of throwing an exception in my class and in the testClass I wrote something like this:

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof exception))]
public void TestTextbox()
{
      Produs target=new Produs();
      target.textbox1.text=""; 
      Assertion.AssertEquals("*",label.text); //label.text should be: 'complete all fields' 
}
```

It is clearly not entirely correct.

Can you please tell me what is the right way to write a test case for a textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NUnit is for unit testing.
What you wanted is probably an Automated/ Coded UI Testing.

If your'e using Visual Studio Ultimate/ Premium, take a look here for Verifying Code by Using UI Automation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx

Comment: Indeed I need to use unit testing and I have to use NUnit. So, what you are saying is that I can not test GUI with NUnit? It's true I am new at unit testing and I thaught that I can test pretty much anything...

Comment: You should try to abstract as much logic from the actual GUI as possible, that way you could unit test the (business) logic and the the presentation separately.

As for the original question, if you're using Windows Forms there's an extension of NUnit for testing UI called NUnitForms (http://nunitforms.sourceforge.net/). I have never use it though, so I can't say much.

Comment: Ok, this might be a stupid question but...it will still be unit testing if I use NUnitForms? I am insisting only on unit testing... and this will be my last question, thank you.

Comment: Hmm, I'm really not sure how to answer that... (NUnitForms says it supports both unit testing and GUI testing). 

Unit testing is executing the smallest individual unit of code (usually a single method but could be methods) and determine if they are fit for use. GUI testing is testing the application GUI to ensure it meets its written specifications (usually means running the whole system/ application). Normally you don't test for GUI in unit testing, and IMO you should never test GUI behavior in unit testing...